# What should I use in CSS to create spaces between my horizontal list items in my navbar?

Tags: css, list, menu, navbar

I am working on an assignment and I need there to be a space between the list items in my navbar. I am using CSS only.

I have already tried changing the margin, block, inline-block, and flex.

```
  .menu {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  }
```

I expect the text laying horizontally on my navbar will have spaces in between each word rather than grouped together.

Comment: You should include more code. If possible link would be really helpful to guide you to solve your issue.

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

To add a space between menu items you can use `justify-content` property:

    `.menu {
        ..
        justify-content: space-around;
    }`

or

    `.menu {
        ..
        justify-content: space-between;
    }`

Comment: Hi thank you for saying that, but I tried that and it isn't working